# Dual oven with 6 wires

Tags: wiring, oven

I bought a used dual oven, which has 6 wires coming out of it.
Unfortunately, it didn't come with a manual, and even the online installation instructions aren't much help. (The manual, as well as the tag on the oven, only refer to "3-wire"...)

Model: Kitchen Aid YKEBS277WB-0
SN: XX4901044

The only manual I've found is [here](http://www.kitchenaid.com/digitalassets/MLPDF/Installation%20Instructions%20-%203177123.pdf).

Pictures of the wires, and where they end up (including the tech sheet that was inside the oven) are available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZfN9.jpg).
I tried calling Kitchen Aid, but they were of no help ("oven is too old"...)

I hooked up red->L1, black->L2, white->neutral, green->ground, and the upper oven worked, but not the lower one. (I wasn't quite sure what to do with blue & yellow.)

Comment: Can you get us more photos of the wiring?

Comment: Kitchen Aid shows a manual without the -0 on the end.  But it lists two wire having two red and two black, hooking the two reds to L1 and the two blacks to L2.

Comment: Which manual are you referring to? The one I linked to (I don't see any references to two red/blacks there, though), or another one?


But either way, I don't have two reds/blacks, only some extraneous blue & yellow. (And unless someone can give me a definitive answer that they should be on L1/L2, I'm a bit hesitant to connect them to anything...)

Comment: Your diagram shows BL (blue) going to L1 .  Are you absolutely sure the "yellow" external wire isn't just an aged, yellowed White?

Comment: There are a ton of installation manuals for "KEBS277" with a variety of suffixes.  They all show only black, red, white, ground coming out of the oven.  https://www.kitchenaid.com/digitalassets/MLPDF/Installation%20Instructions%20-%204448970.pdf

Comment: Probably the yellow and the blue go to L1 and L2 (blue connects to black and yellow connects to red. Can you trace the wires in the oven? does it look like the yellow serves the same function as the red, and the blue the same function as the black? Can you measure the resistance of the heating element in the currently working oven (red-to black resistance) with the oven disconnected and the temp control on high? If so, try this between yellow and blue. http://www.doityourself.com/stry/220-wiring-color-code-interpretation

Comment: "Probably the yellow and the blue go to L1 and L2" - I followed your advice, and everything seems to be working fine with this setup (all hooked up to one 40amp breaker). Thanks!

Comment: @Frescard -- post that as an answer and I'll toss you an upvote bone :)

Answer (score 1):

I've followed Jim's advice, and connected red & yellow to L1, and black & blue to L2, and everything is working fine now.